# Add a chidren at first of component children

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I create an wrapper for `Picker` component And I want to add a child in condition

I try this code

```
render() {
    const { children, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Picker {...rest}>
        {rest.selectedValue === undefined ? (
          <Picker.Item value="1" label="1" />
        ) : null}
        {children}
      </Picker>
    );
  }
```

And I get this error

> TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating 'o.props')

I also try with `undefiened` instead of `null` and `short circuit` condition but I get error in that case too.

**Also** note If I remove condition and just add an element before children its work. something like this

```
<Picker.Item value="1" label="1" />
{children}
```

**UPDATED**

I found the problem is when condition is false for example this make error

```
{false && (<Picker.Item value="1" label="1" />)}
```

expo project https://snack.expo.io/@cooper47/mad-waffle
( **change picker and see the error** )

I think the problem is when I concat `children` with `undefined` ( result of condtion ) because when I try this I get same error

```
<Picker {...rest}>
   {undefined} // result of short circuit 
   {children} 
</Picker>
```

- Why I get this error with conditon and get no error without condition?
- How I can add an element before `this.props.children`?
- Is there anyway add element at first of `children`? for example `children.add(<Picker.Item...>)`

I found out actually its a bug in react-native

Here is the relative issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25141#issuecomment-498651856

Comment: can you add the full code of your component?

Comment: @vd_virani it's only have `render` and I put all render content.

Comment: @DennisVash I update my expo with your answer ( check rest ) and you can see still get same error, https://snack.expo.io/@cooper47/mad-waffle

Comment: @DennisVash also I update the error message `TypeError: null is not an object`

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi answer updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: There is no problem with the condition, the error depends on the wrapper (Picker) internal calls.

My guess is that `Picker` internal calls its children props (expects `Picker.Item`), it may check your condition `props` when it falsy and therefore throw an error of `undefined props`.

```js
<Picker>
  {condition && <Picker.Item value="1" label="1" />}   
  // ^ Picker wrapper may check null.props, undefined.props, false.props etc

  {children}
</Picker>
```

In this case, make the condition outside the render:

```js
  const conditionChildren = condition ? (
    <> <Picker /> {children} </> ) : (children);
  return {conditionChildren}
```

> How I can add an element before this.props.children?

Use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) or call the component inline:

```js
function ConditionChildren({ children, condition }) {
  return (
    <>
      {condition && <Picker />}
      // or {condition && React.createElement(Picker)}
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

> Is there anyway add an element at first of children? for example children.add()

```js
  const addFirstToChildren = [
    React.createElement(Picker),
    ...React.Children.toArray(children)
  ];
return {addFirstToChildren}
```

Check the demo with the generic solution:

[image: Edit zealous-heyrovsky-exec8]

Comment: Yeah createElement would work for this, wrapper can be functional component.

Comment: Your error is a problem with calling the component and not adding component before the children

Comment: Ok I'm trying with expo and share link if get an error

Comment: Try  `rest && rest.selectedValue  && (<Picker.Item value="1" label="1" />)`  you not checking if rest is undefined

Comment: I update my expo, Also I figure out when the selectedValue changed the error occured ( when the condtion is false )

Comment: Yea it was my guess, `Picker` checks `props` of it children, anyways hope my answer was helpful cheers

Comment: @DennisVash actually its a bug and will be fixed in next released, I update my question with link, anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for PureComponent

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Picker } from 'react-native'

export default class SelectBox extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    }
    render() {
     const { options, value, onChageText } = this.props
      let Alloptions = options.map((item, key) => {
         return (<Picker.Item label={item.name} value={item.value} key={key} />)
      })
      return (
        <Picker selectedValue={value} onValueChange={onChageText}>
       {/* If you want to add default option here  */}
         {/* <Picker.Item label="Select Location..." value="" /> */}
              {Alloptions}
        </Picker>
     )
    }
}
```

and your Component Like

```
<SelectBox
options={[{name:'aaa',value:'11'},{name:'bbbb',value:'22'}]}
value={''}
onChageText={this.selectLocation}
/>
 selectLocation(itemValue, itemIndex) {
...your code
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `If you want to add default option here` my problem extacly is here If I add an default value with **condition** I get an error.

Comment: pass  value = '' and and your default option is set